# Problem on Sum of Digits of a Number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was given this problem to Prove if $Q(n)=Q(2n)$ implies $9∣n$. Where $Q(n)$ be the sum of digits of $n$. I tried to use the fact that sum of digits is congruent to the number modulo $9$ but I had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By your fact:

$$Q(n)\equiv n \pmod 9,\quad Q(2n)\equiv 2n \pmod 9$$

Hence:

$$Q(n) = Q(2n) \implies n\equiv 2n \pmod 9 \implies n \equiv 0 \pmod 9$$

thus $9 \mid n$.

Comment: Thank you I actually just solved it like this guess shouldve waited longer to post the question,

Comment: If you solved it before anyone else does, you can delete your question or answer your own question. I think you can't delete the question after someone has posted a solution, though.

Comment: @player3236 FYI, see the "When *can't* I delete my own post?" section in the answer to [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/562482). As it states there, generally, as long as there are no answers, or just one answer with no upvotes, the OP can delete their question.